# Python Logger exception is logged as trace in Azure Application Insights (Azure Function)

Tags: python, azure, function, logging

I try to log handled exception from my Python Azure Function in Application Insights as exception. Whatever i do it is always written as track with error severity level. Output in local console is "red" as excepted.

**What i tried:**

- Changing function.json logging section to:

  ```
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Error"
    }
  ```
- various calls of exception method

```py
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("An error has occured",exc_info=e)
        logger.exception("An error has occured")
        logger.exception()
```

- tried to call telmetry client directly

```
    tc.track_exception()
```

- clearing and adding handlers to logger

## Edit:

Example to clarify what i mean:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzhVC.png)

Comment: Try this `logger.error('My exception', exc_info=True)`

Comment: Didn't work. Exception is still logged as trace with error severity level in application insights.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand what you want. You'd like to log the exception as plain string ? Because, then use you'll have to use `logger.error('My exception: {}.format(e))`

Comment: I would like to log my exception as exception in application insights. Currently it is logged as a trace

Comment: So isn't my below answer okay ? Gives you both formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logging the exception as plain text instead of logging a full trace goes like the following:

```py
handler = AzureLogHandler(connection_string = "instrmental key here")
handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(handler)
try:
    raise Exception("test")
except Exception as e:
    # Logging as string
    logger.debug('The following error has occured: {0}'.format(e))
    # Logging as full trace
    # logger.debug('The following error was traced:', exc_info=True)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer! When I added AzureLogHandler it started to work but now my excepions are logged twice.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to  Orsiris de Jong after many hours of fight I found the solution:

```
handler = AzureLogHandler(connection_string = "instrmental key here")
handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.propagate = False
if(handler not in logger.handlers):
    logger.addHandler(handler)
try:
    raise Exception("test")
except Exception as e:
    logger.exception('An error has occured', exc_info=True)
```

This handler changed trace into exception in Application Insights and resolved problem with double logging